# Defaults documentation for builtin apps?

Tags: macos, defaults, documentation

Does Apple supply a list of valid preferences, in terms of key-value pairs found in plist files, for built-in OS X apps?

For example, the Preview app has a user setting for anti-aliasing. One can turn this off from the command line with

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview PVPDFAntiAliasOption -bool no
```

This can also be done from the PDF tab of the Preview preferences pane, and if I do the command

```
defaults read com.apple.Preview
```

I am able to see all of Preview's stored defaults, and might be able to deduce without foreknowledge that `PVPDFAntiAliasOption` would be the key-value pair to alter to get the desired behaviour.

But now suppose I would like to modify other behaviours for Preview, which do not have entries in the preferences pane. Say have the sidebar open by default to the table of contents, instead of thumbnails. Or have the sidebar not open at all.

I am unable to find documentation on developer.apple.com which even lists the known `PVPDFAntiAliasOption`, let alone the (non-)existence of unknown keys. Google will find information about this known key, but I haven't found the right combination of search terms to find the desired list. Does documentation exist for these items? Is it provided by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There are many hidden settings that users figure out themselves, as Apple has not published a list showing which preferences are available